# ReactJS - use state with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

```
const [firstName, getFullName] => useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
   getFullName();
}); 

function getFullName() {
   apiService.getFullName().then(function (x) { //data[0] = Mark, data[1] = Louis
       getFullName(x.data[0]);
   });
}
```

I would like to have another variable called `lastName` and assign `Louis`.

How can I do that?

Comment: the exact same way, you call useState again and assign a new variable and new setter function, btw there seems to be a syntax error in your first line of code

Comment: why do you instantiate the firstName state with a boolean value ? why not use an  object with 2 keys, firstname and lastname ? of type string i presume

Comment: Also, you should pick an answer if it helped you. Upvote it. Or comment if it didn't solve your problem. People use their time to help you ( for free ). You can at least upvote/interact with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by changing your `firstName` string with an object (called `fullName`) with 2 keys like this

`const [fullName, setFullName] => useState({ firstName: '', lastName: ''});`

```
                                               /\ 
                                               ||
                         Default value here instead of `useState(true)` as yours :(
```

```js
const [fullName, setFullName] => useState({ firstName: '', lastName: ''});

useEffect(() => {
   getFullName();
}); 

function getFullName() {
   apiService.getFullName().then(function (x) { //data[0] = Mark, data[1] = Louis
       setFullName({
        firstName: x.data[0],
        lastName: x.data[1]
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: missing a closing `)` on useState. And for clarity reasons use `setFullName` instead of `getFullName` as the set state method

Comment: @MihaiT I've just updated my answer based on your advice. Pls take a look at, Thanks ^^!

Comment: @HappySnowman Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

**Add another state that indicates `lastname`.**

---

`getFullName` is the method for set, so better to rename it to `setFirstname`.

Refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean

```
const [firstName, setFirstname] => useState('');
const [lastName, setLastname] => useState('');

useEffect(() => {
   getFullName();
}); 

function getFullName() {
   apiService.getFullName().then(function (x) { //data[0] = Mark, data[1] = Louis
       setFirstname(x.data[0]);
       setLastname(x.data[1]);
   });
}
```